# How to turn repeated index values into a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df`:

```
  x
0 a
1 b
2 c
0 a
1 b
2 c
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

How can I turn those duplicated index values to new rows? Desired output:

```
  x  y  z
0 a  a  a
1 b  b  b
2 c  c  c
```

I have been trying to add new columns to a dataframe through a loop with `append`, but it just keeps giving me this output by adding rows instead of columns. I tried `join` but that didn't work either, so i figured there must just be a hacky way to turn these repreated index values to new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(df.groupby(level=0).agg(list)["x"].apply(pd.Series))
```

Prints:

```
   0  1  2
0  a  a  a
1  b  b  b
2  c  c  c
```

---

To rename columns:

```py
print(
    df.groupby(level=0)
    .agg(list)["x"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns={0: "x", 1: "y", 2: "z"})
)
```

Prints:

```
   x  y  z
0  a  a  a
1  b  b  b
2  c  c  c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#change column name as required.
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.index).values.apply(list).to_list())
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'values'